# laravel auth::attempt() gives error when specifying a known username

Tags: php, laravel

Hi i'm new to laravel and was trying to use the auth system.

the problem i'm having is that when verifying the users username and password by auth::attemp() I end up with a 'whoops something went wrong page' but only when there is a known username being specified. When i'm inputting an unkown username i get the expected error page.

i've created an user by:

```
// add user
$user = new User;
$user->username = 'John';
$user->password = Hash::make('Doe');
$user->email    = 'info@mail.com';
$user->save();
```

the route i've created for the post method looks like this:

```
Route::post('login', function(){
    $credentials = array(
        'username' => Input::get('username'),
        'password' => Input::get('password')
    );

    // check credentials
    if (Auth::attempt($credentials)) {
        // go to index if login is successful
        return Redirect::to('/');
    }

    // fail
    return Redirect::to('login')->with('error' , 'Wrong username or password');
});
```

Now as i've said the error message is being shown if I specify an username wich is not (in this case) 'John'. when is do use 'John' I end up with an error no matter the password is correct or incorrect.

my question: What am i doing wrong here? and how to fix it?

Comment: Can you do a `var_dump($credentials);` (assuming the password isn't secret) so we can confirm the `username`?

Comment: The reason you're seeing "whoops something went wrong page" is because you haven't turned on debug in `config/app.php`, set that to true and you'll have more insight into what's going wrong. Development/testing environments should always have this set to true.

Comment: Your `User` model also might not be set up to accept a username/password combo. By default, it's email/password.

Comment: var_dump($credentials) gives : array(2) { ["username"]=> string(4) "John" ["password"]=> string(3) "Doe" }.

Comment: i've turned on debug on. the error message i'm getting: Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Auth\EloquentUserProvider::validateCredentials() must be an instance of Illuminate\Auth\UserInterface, instance of User given, called in C:\xampp\htdocs\test\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Auth\Guard.php on line 361 and defined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out to be a really stupid mistake. I edited the User model (app/models/User.php), this was causing the problem. I've reverted back to the original and everything works fine now!

Thanks for the help guys!